# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'something' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
,iif(([CreatedDateTime] IS NOT NULL 
AND 
migrationdatetime IS NOT NULL), datediff(day,[CreatedDateTime],[MigrationDateTime]),'not moved to prd')
```

and basically if either of these date is null I want to display a text.
is there any reason why I get this error"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'something' to data type int"
 How can I resolve it?
Appreciate your help

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Oh cool ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression is an expression is an expression.  And -- like the colors of many roses -- has only one type.  It cannot be both a string and a date.

By the type precedence rules of *SQL*, when a string and a number are the choices, the number is the dominant type; so the string is converted to a number. And you get a conversion error.

So, use `CONVERT()`, `CAST()` or `FORMAT()`:

```
(CASE WHEN CreatedDateTime IS NOT NULL AND migrationdatetime IS NOT NULL
      THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DATEDIFF(DAY, CreatedDateTime, MigrationDateTime))
      ELSE 'not moved to prd'
 END)
```

Of course, given the rules of `NULL`s in SQL, this is more simply written as:

```
      COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), DATEDIFF(DAY, CreatedDateTime, MigrationDateTime)),
               'not moved to prd'
              )
```

Comment: I put the formula, got this error: 'VARCHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name." @Gordon Linoff

Comment: Get rid of the closing square bracket after migrationdatetime

Comment: Your solution was correct, however, I needed to have "As VARCHAR(255)" at the end of statement.@Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

I used the same but it works perfect

```
DECLARE @CreatedDateTime Varchar(30) = getdate(), @migrationdatetime  Varchar(30) = dateAdd(MM,2,getdate())

Select iif((@CreatedDateTime IS NOT NULL AND @migrationdatetime IS NOT NULL), datediff(day,@CreatedDateTime,@MigrationDateTime),'not moved to prd')
```

I think date format in varchar is not correct. you need to look into the record